# Pass variables from page to another page. Flutter/Dart

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have some variables in one page and i want to pass it to another page when navigate.
first page codes with variables:

```
int groupValue = -1;
  int idButton = 0;
 onTap: (){
                     Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                       builder: (context) => SearchResault(),
                       settings: RouteSettings(
                         arguments: {
                          IdButton,
                           groupValue
    }
                       )
                     ));
                    },
```

the problem is that every time i get {-1,0} but i want to choose what i want to RECIVE.

*EDITED*

This is the edited code down here:
You can just pass the argument through the constructor of your widget, as such:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
       MaterialPageRoute(builder:
         (BuildContext context) =>
           SearchResault(idButton: IdButton, groupValue: groupValue),
         ),
       );
```

You can then define your stateless widget :

```
class SearchResault extends StatelessWidget {
  final int idButton;
  final int groupValue;

  const SearchResault({this.idButton, this.groupValue});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
               body: Container(
                  child: Text("${idButton} - ${groupValue}")
            );
  }
}
```

Comment: Post you full second widget code as well.

Comment: It's empty I did't code anything

Comment: Post your full app code.

Comment: it's about 1000 lines bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the argument through the constructor of your widget, as such:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
       MaterialPageRoute(builder:
         (BuildContext context) =>
           SearchResault(idButton: IdButton, groupValue: groupValue),
         ),
       );
```

You can then define your stateless widget :

```dart
class SearchResault extends StatelessWidget {
  final int idButton;
  final int groupValue;

  const SearchResault({this.idButton, this.groupValue});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
               body: Container(
                  child: Text("${idButton} - ${groupValue}")
            );
  }
}
```

Comment: And how can i receive into another page?

Comment: I updated my example. You push arguments from one view with the `Navigator.of(context).push` method, then you get access to them in the widget you pushed since you provide it with arguments in his constructor.